# randoming translation in GLUT turns bad

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

this is my cube. Once created, it has a random x position on either -2, -1, 0, 1, or 2.

```
void cube(void)
{
    srand (time(0));

    int cube_posX;
    int lowv = -2;
    int highv = 2;

    cube_posX = rand() % (highv - lowv + 1) + lowv;

    glTranslatef(cube_posX, 0.0, cube_angle);
    glRotatef(cube_angle, 90.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glutSolidCube(0.25);
}
```

and this is how I move the cube slowly forward

```
void MOVE_CUBE(int value)
{
    cube_posZ = cube_posZ - 0.01;
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(25, MOVE_CUBE, 0);
}
```

and finally putting them in display:

```
void init(void)
{
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
}

float cam_eyeX = 0.0, cam_eyeY = 1.5, cam_eyeZ = 5.0;
float cam_centerX = 0.0, cam_centerY = 0.0, cam_centerZ = 0.0;
void display(void)
{
    glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);      //to add background color (white)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(cam_eyeX, cam_eyeY, cam_eyeZ, cam_centerX, cam_centerY, cam_centerZ, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);  //camera! (cam position X, cam position Y, cam position Z, cam target X, cam target Y, cam target Z,  up position X, up position Y, up position Z)

    cube();

    glutSwapBuffers();
    angle += 0.05; //to affect the glRotate function
    glFlush();
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport (0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);
    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity ();
    gluPerspective (60, (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h, 1.0, 100.0);
    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);      // Set up display buffer 
    glutInitWindowSize(750, 500);       //window's size
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);   //window's position
    glutCreateWindow("Hendra Ganteng!");  //window's title
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc (display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard_Handler);

    MOVE_CUBE(0);

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

But when I see it in action, the cube moves forward flawlessly, but keeps changing x position onto those 5 possibilities (-2,-1,0,1,2) every 0.5 to 1 second. If I disable the srand(time(0)), the cube changes its x position rapidly. I just want to make it stay in 1 x position so then I can call more cubes in different x position. Could someone please kindly what's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is that behaviour not expected?  You are generating a random X position every time you display your cube.  If you re-seed the random number generator using the time, then it will be start a different sequence whenever the time changes (once per second).

Instead, you should pre-generate your cube(s).  How about this:

```
// Global cube data
struct Cube {
    int x;
    double angle;
};

vector<Cube> cubes;
const int num_cubes = 1;

// Example initialisation...
void InitCubes()
{
    cubes.reserve(num_cubes);

    for( int i = 0; i < num_cubes; i++ )
    {
        Cube cube;
        cube.x = rand() % (highv - lowv + 1) + lowv;
        cube.angle = 0.0;
        cubes.push_back(cube);
    }
}
```

Now the update/display cycles simply need to modify the angle, but not the x-position.

```
void UpdateCube( Cube & cube )
{
    cube.angle += 0.05;
}

void DisplayCube( Cube & cube )
{
    glTranslatef((double)cube.x, 0.0, cube.angle);
    glRotatef(cube.angle, 90.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glutSolidCube(0.25);
}
```

In your **main** function, call `InitCubes()` during startup.

In your **display** function, do this:

```
void display(void)
{
    glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(cam_eyeX, cam_eyeY, cam_eyeZ, cam_centerX, cam_centerY, cam_centerZ, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);    

    // Display cubes        
    for( int i = 0; i < cubes.size(); i++ ) DisplayCube( cubes[i] );

    glutSwapBuffers();
    glFlush();

    // Update cubes for next render cycle.
    for( int i = 0; i < cubes.size(); i++ ) UpdateCube( cubes[i] );
}
```

Comment: I seem to have a problem "pre-generating" the cube, I do not understand in which section the for looping belongs to. I copy and pasted your code under the function void display (void) in my source code above, the result is that the cubes are still switching x position rapidly.. I'm not as programming experts as many here, I would appreciate simpler explanation. Thanks!

Comment: When we talk about generating, and especially "pre-generating", we mean do it *once* before any of the remaining code.  That means, *don't* generate inside your `display` function.  The whole point is you create a cube in a random position *once*, and then update and display it many times.

Comment: You need to pass a `Cube` instance into the function!  I edited my answer to try and make it obvious how you should be using the code.

Comment: that's very nice of you, I deeply appreciate it. But somehow the cubes stays in same position x = 1. No matter how many num_cubes I add or how many times I tried it running, the x position now stuck to 1..

Comment: Make sure you're not using those old position and angle variables during display.  It's easy to accidentally forget to use the new ones (in the `Cube` structure).  If in doubt, feel free to edit your question and post your current code.  The other thing to consider is that if you just have one cube, you need to seed the random number generator - the common way to do this is `srand(time(0));`.  Do this once at the beginning of your program, before any calls to `rand()` are made.

Comment: totally works after minutes trying to understand the logic, thanks for being very helpful!

Comment: oh I got 1 more concern: I used glutTimerFunc in order to move the cube z position smoothly (see my function MOVE_CUBE above). can it somehow be used in multiple cubes in your code? or do I need to find another way to do so?

Comment: That's where your update function comes in.  Just add a `z` position to the `Cube` structure and update that accordingly.  Instead of calling `UpdateCube` from your `display` function, maybe you want to call it from `MOVE_CUBE`.